# Is there a method just write `---` to get an em-dash, putting thinspace both before and after it?

Tags: spacing, punctuation, kerning

Is there a method just write `---` to get an em-dash, putting a thinspace both before and after it?
The situation about break is similar with the original ---.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`microtype`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[kerning=true]{microtype}
\SetExtraKerning
    {encoding =  {OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,T5,TS1,EU1,EU2}} % all text
    {
        \textemdash  = {167,167} % thinspace = 1/6 em
    }

\begin{document}

Single hyphen in text mode: text-text, and in math mode: $a-b$.

Double hyphen in text mode: text--text, and in math mode: $a--b$.

Triple hyphen in text mode: text---text, and in math mode: $a---b$.

Quadruple hyphen in text mode: text----text, and in math mode: $a----b$.

\end{document}
```

Compiled:
[image: compiled example]

400% zoom:
[image: compiled example - zoom]

If you do not like other `microtype` features (i.e., protrusion and expansion), you can disable them by adding respective options to `\usepackage`.

Comment: For a thin space is should be `{167,167}`, as `1000` refers to the em in the current font and the normal width of the thin space is 1/6 em.

Comment: @egreg Where is `\thinspace` defined as 1/6 em? (Not that I don't believe you.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg `texdef -t latex thinspace` says `\kern 1.66667em`

Comment: @egreg, you're rigth. Corrected and added zoom.
@SvendTveskæg, `latex.ltx` says `\def\thinspace{\kern .16667em }`

Comment: Should one really list TS1? It gives a warning:
`Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                \`\textemdash '
(microtype)                in font encoding \`TS1' in kerning list
(microtype)                \`thesis-main.tex/32'.`