# Redefining --- ligature

Tags: spacing, punctuation

Is there a way of redefining the em-dash ligature `---` so as to mean `\,---\,`?
Something like:

```
\let\oldemdash---
\def---{\,\oldemdash\,}
```

which of course doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try redefining plain old `\emdash`? I seem to remember that control sequence existing (and being the root definition of `---`).

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109156/is-there-a-method-just-write-to-get-an-em-dash-putting-thinspace-both-bef/109188#109188

Comment: `\emdash` doesn't exist, I belief. It is `\textemdash`, but redefining it doesn't change the behavior of `---`. The other solution suggested (using `microtype`) also doesn't work, as it changes the kerning of `\textemdash` not of `---`. One possibility would be changing all the `---` tokens in my document for the redefined `\textemdash`, but I could simply change them also for `\,---,`.

Comment: I came looking for this after I saw http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91410 --- my mistake