# How to leave a space after an em-dash with xspace

Tags: spacing, punctuation, xspace

I wish to have  a space between and after my em-dashes as I do not like the english tradition to collate them to the nearest words.
[`xspace`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace) permits to leave spaces for macros but does not handle well the `---` via its exception rules.
There is an illustration on page 3 of its PDF
http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/xspace.pdf
to manage the `-`, but I cannot get it right for `---`.
`\xspaceremoveexception{--(-)}` does not seem to work because, evidently, I wish the en-dash `--` to remain as it is: no space after the macro `\mymacro--`sometext, since by definition, these `--` are used to indicate a range.
Here is a MWE to illustrate with the hack commented from the PDF:

```
 %\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xspace}

%\xspaceremoveexception{-}
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*\@xspace@hook{%
%\ifx\@let@token--%
%\expandafter\@xspace@dash@iii
%\fi
%}
%\def\@xspace@dash@i-{\futurelet\@let@token\@xspace@dash@ii}
%\def\@xspace@dash@ii{%
%\ifx\@let@token-%
%\else
%\unskip
%\fi
%-%
%}
%\makeatother




%\xspaceremoveexception{--}

\newcommand{\bla}{January}

\newcommand{\blaa}{{January}\xspace}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%é


\begin{document}


without xspace:\\
 \bla --- ouoiuoiuou --- \bla ; \bla (\bla)

with xspace: the parenthesis improves, not the --- :\\
 \blaa --- ouoiuoiuou --- \blaa ; \blaa (\blaa)

\blaa --December   \blaa--December

\blaa -December
\end{document}




%\xspaceremoveexception{-}
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*\@xspace@hook{%
%\ifx\@let@token-%
%\expandafter\@xspace@dash@i
%\fi
%}
%\def\@xspace@dash@i-{\futurelet\@let@token\@xspace@dash@ii}
%\def\@xspace@dash@ii{%
%\ifx\@let@token-%
%\else
%\unskip
%\fi
%-%
%}
%\makeatother
```

Comment: Knuth defined somewhere a `\dash` macro which I have used in the past.

Comment: This question seems to have a better answer elsewhere, based on microtype: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109188/1340. You still write `---` for an em-dash, and use microtype to give it extra kerning.

Answer (score 2):

As a "hacky solution", what I do is to create a command `\newcommand{\emdash}{\,---\,}` and then `\renewcommand{\emdash}{---}` for documents where I don't want enclosing spaces.

Comment: Possibly adding `\unskip` at the front and `\ignorespaces` at the end to be on the safe side.